# An esoteric example of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let us consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a field, $V=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ as the set of positive real numbers, the usual product in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ as sum and the exponentiation $v^\alpha$ with $v \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ as scalar multiplication.

I proved that it is a vector space, but I can't figure out why. I found it referred as 'an esoteric example' on AGLQ. Is there a reason for that or is it just a tricky way to name the last excercise of the page?

Comment: You proved it but you can't figure out why? I would argue that "why" is exactly the proof. Maybe your question is somehow different/more specific?

Comment: All right, I give up: what's AGLQ?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley https://www.math.unipd.it/~maurizio/g1/AGLQpp.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can transform $V$ to $\mathbb R$ by taking the logarithm (bijective function). Then, using $x=\ln v$, $y=\ln u$, with $u,v\in V$, you get:
$$\ln(uv)=\ln u+\ln v=x+y\\\ln(u^\alpha)=\alpha\ln u=\alpha x$$
Esoteric means jut hard to understand. But with the transformation above it looks simple.